# Show a text if the post has written by author user role in Wordpress

Tags: php, posts, post-meta

I search a PHP code what is show a certain text or html code on the post page when the post author is an author. (not admin or editor)

When the post author is an admin or editor then show nothing.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure what you're trying to ask for? It would be more better if you could add more explanation or some code that you've tried so far. If you're intent to ask that on front end post page is visited by author of the post and he can show some special extra peace of lines or HTML!

Comment: I search a PHP code:
If the post author is from specific user role, (author) then show something...
Else do not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it:

```
global $post;
$user = get_user_by( 'ID', $post->post_author );
if ( in_array( 'author', $user->roles ) ) {echo "Author";}
```

You don't even need `global $post;` if you are if a query loop.